# Accuse someone of having manners

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across the following sentence in a book, and I'm not sure of its meaning. The quote is:

> “It would be rude to refuse a gift,” Blake said, eyes cast over her [Weiss'] head towards Cinder, “especially one so hard-won.”
>
> Out of the corner of her eye, Weiss saw the same fingers that had clasped hers adjust that ashen scarf. “I’d never accuse you of having manners, Blake.”
>
> “For which I’m grateful.” Blake replied dryly.

Comment: It's a joke. Asserting that someone has manners is typically received as a *compliment*, not an *accusation* (ie typically it's taken as *credit*, not *blame*). So negating it is a back-handed compliment: a way of stating your interlocutor is uncouth while implying you're saying something nice (withholding an *accusation*).

Comment: @DanBron That may be some kind of a listed literary device. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_technique

Comment: It's a sarcastic way of saying "You have no manners".

Comment: _Accuse_ is one of the verbs Fillmore called _Verbs of Judging_ in his famous article; McCawley summarizes and extends the semantics in his famous article, _Verbs of Bitching_, most of which is [available online in Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=-5OQs4UokQoC&lpg=PA313&ots=b4ZQrSr8v2&dq=fillmore%20%22verbs%20of%20judging%22&pg=PA322#v=onepage&q=fillmore%20%22verbs%20of%20judging%22&f=false).